# How does shared memory work

Tags: linux, memory

I don't understand very well what's the difference between shared memory and the rest of the memory present on the system.

For example if i have 8GB or Memory (swap and RAM both included) , and i have 4GB on /dev/shm. does /dev/shm reserve this portion of memory and don't allow applications to get some of it if needed (if they need normal memory no shared memory) ?
My question can be a little confusing because i don't have a grasp on the subject.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
mount | grep -F /dev/shm
```

to learn that `/dev/shm` is using the [`tmpfs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) filesystem:

> […] unlike ramfs it supports swapping out less-used pages to swap space, as well as filesystem size and inode limits to prevent out of memory situations (defaulting to half of physical RAM and half the number of RAM pages, respectively).

`ramfs` is a similar one, but it doesn't put any limits on memory usage and doesn't track it, so it should be used very carefully.